# Filtering users from a CSV then removing those filtered users from specific security groups with Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, active-directory

I am trying to write a PowerShell program that will take an imported CSV of active and inactive accounts and then filter those users by a keyword (disabled) which successfully works. I get a filtered CSV with a timestamp for auditing purposes in the file name

This is an example from the imported CSV

```
Username,Name,Email,Status,Created,Last Login
Test,"Test, Test",Test@Test.DC502.com,Active,2018-12-07 21:46:40 UTC,2024-03-18 20:01:50
```

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

# Gathers Date information and creates CSV naming convention for Filtered CSV Output
$TimeStamp = Get-date -Format "MMddyy"
$filters = "Disabled"

# User drops file named Removal to Desktop
Get-Content -Path 'c:\Scripts\UsersTest.csv' | Select-String -Pattern $filters | Out-File -FilePath "c:\Logs\$TimeStamp FilteredUsersForRemoval.csv"
```

This is an example from the CSV output

```
Test2,"Test2,Test2",Test@Test.DC502.com,Disabled,2018-12-07 21:46:40 UTC,2024-03-18 20:01:50
```

A note that I want to add is that in the exported CSV from filtering, there are no headers in the file, just the data

The next part removes those specific filtered users by matching their UPN in AD with their Email from the CSV

```
$GroupFilter = 'MFA Offline Access', 'Personal Phone', 'MFAUsers', 'Test Domain 1 users', 'Test Domain 2 Users'
$Users= "c:\Logs\$TimeStamp FilteredUsersForRemoval.csv"

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    $UPN = $User.Username
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Email' -like $UPN | Select-Object SamAccountName
    {
        $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $ADUser.SamAccountName | Select-Object Name
        if ($ExistingGroups.Name -eq $GroupFilter)
            {
                Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupFilter-Members $ADUser.SamAccountName -Confirm$false
                Write-Host "Removed $UPN from $Group" - ForeGroundColor Green
            }
        else
            {
                Write-Host "$UPN does not exist in $Group" - ForeGroundColor Yellow
            }
    }
}
```

This is the part that is constantly failing and giving errors such as a parameter can't be found for -like or -eq.

In our live domain, these specific users are inside mutiple OU's - Example Test> > Users > Terminated and that is where thse disabled users are that I am trying to remove groups from.

The specific groups that are needing to be removed from these users are in the $GroupFilter variable.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with syntax or the CSV imports

```
    foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    $UPN = $User.Email
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {Email -like $UPN} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName 
    {
        $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $ADUser.UserPrincipalName  | Select-Object Name
        if ($ExistingGroups[0].Name -eq $GroupFilter)
            {
                Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupFilter-Members $ADUser.UserPrincipalName
                Write-Host "Removed $UPN from $Group" - ForeGroundColor Green
            }
        else
            {
                Write-Host "$UPN does not exist in $Group" - ForeGroundColor Yellow
            }
    }
}
```

With the new snippet, $UPN is coming back as undefined. Another issue that i figured out or believe to be correct is that the Email in the CSV is what needs to be compared and not the username so i made those changes and I beleive them to be correct.

Overall the Email in the CSV is needing to be compared to the UPN in AD, not the SAM.

Comment: $ExistingGroups is an array.  Try if ($ExistingGroups[0].Name -eq $GroupFilter)

Comment: The `Username` column of the CSV is the user's `SamAccountName` ?

Comment: Your ```-filter``` on ```get-aduser``` is not correct, it is seeing ```-like``` as a potential parameter of ```get-aduser``` and not a part of the filter. Try the following ```Get-ADUser -Filter {Email -like $UPN}```. It is also worth noting that when using the ```-like``` comparison operator you will need to use wildcards to get results if the comparing array does not contain the exact value. e.g. ```Get-ADUser -Filter {Email -like "test*"}```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem starts where you (mis)treat the input CSV as plain text by using `Get-Content` instead of `Import-Csv` and `Out-File` instead of `Export-Csv`..

Using a `Where-Object` clause, you can filter out the disabled users from the original input csv file immediately, so basically there would be no need to store a subset into a new file, except maybe for later reference.

Try

```
# Gathers Date information and creates CSV naming convention for Filtered CSV Output
$TimeStamp = Get-date -Format "MMddyy"
# read and parse the input csv, collect only user objects that are disabled
$Users     = Import-Csv -Path 'c:\Scripts\UsersTest.csv' | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Disabled'}

# for later reference write the disabled users in a separate output csv
$Users | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Logs\$TimeStamp FilteredUsersForRemoval.csv" -NoTypeInformation

$GroupFilter = 'MFA Offline Access', 'Personal Phone', 'MFAUsers', 'Test Domain 1 users', 'Test Domain 2 Users'

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($User.Email)'" -Properties EmailAddress

    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ADUser.DistinguishedName |  # get the groups this user belongs to
    Where-Object {$GroupFilter -contains $_.Name} |                       # filter to get only the groups in $GroupFilter
    ForEach-Object {                                                      # loop over these groups and remove the user
        $_ | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $ADUser
        Write-Host "Removed $($ADUser.Name) from $($_.Name)" -ForeGroundColor Green
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying your code I'm not getting an error with

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ADUser.DistinguishedName

Error is stating that it is either null or empty

Comment: @Trikru502 That would mean no user is found in your AD with an email address equal to the address in your input CSV under header Email. Please make sure your test csv uses existing email addresses there. Otherwise, you could try to find the user by filtering on the Username from the CSV with `-Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($User.UserName)'"` or just `Get-ADUser -Identity $User.UserName`. If what is listed under column `Email` is in fact the UserPrincipalName, change the code to use `$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($User.Email)'"`

Comment: I found the issue! Tested multiple times and functions correctly! Thank you for the help

Comment: @Trikru502 Aha, that's good to hear! If you find my answer helped solve your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the large checkmark icon. This helps others with a similar question find it more easily.